# Bigdecimal parsed to Double in Properties?

Tags: codenameone

I'm rewriting the core of one of my apps, and one of the major change is migrating my entities to `PropertyBusinessObjects`.

I've coded a little tool to write `PropertyBusinessObjects` from my server side `JPAEntities` to limit the time taken by stupid copy pasting and leverage my workload, so nearly all my CN1 entities are rewritten to PBO.

In order to not rewrite all of the code which was using `classic getters/setters`, I've added the creation of `pseudo getter/setters` to my generation code to obtain this kind of result :

```
protected Property<String, Product> reference = new Property<>("reference");
public String getReference() {
    return this.reference.get();
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference.set(reference);
}
```

The result is nearly perfect, but I've run into some troubles when it comes to `BigDecimal`. Our app is an ERP client (mainly a consultation app which is combined with a much bigger webapp), so when it come to price values and so on, we need high precision, which lead us to `BigDecimals` years ago.

When I retrieve my entities from the server, everything goes well, all is read by the `getAsProperties` from the `RequestBuilder` without any exceptions. But when it goes through my "getter", the call throws a `ClassCastException`. It appears that the parsed value for the `BigDecimals` are `Doubles`, so it sets my `Property<BigDecimal, Product>` with a `Double` value instead of a `BigDecimal` which later cause `ClassCastExceptions`.

Here is an exemple of `BigDecimal` property and its getter/setter :

```
protected Property<BigDecimal, Product> priceBuy = new Property<>("priceBuy", BigDecimal.class);
public BigDecimal getPriceBuy() {
    return this.priceBuy.get();
}


public void setPriceBuy(BigDecimal priceBuy) {
    this.priceBuy.set(priceBuy);
}
```

Any idea or leads to resolve this matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no logic for parsing/placing `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` in properties. This might be something we should add in the future, however as a workaround we have a generic extension mechanism that lets you customize this code.

Haven't tried this but it should generally work:

```
MapAdapter m = new MapAdapter(BigDecimal.class) {
    public void placeInMap(PropertyBase b, Map m) {
        // this might be unnecessary
        m.put(b.getName(), b.get());
    }

    public void setFromMap(PropertyBase b, Map m){
        long d = (long)(m.get(b.getName()) * 10000);

        b.setImpl(new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(d), 5));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, I've forgot that I've already used this in another app for an enumeration property. It works fine when reading data, I've still not have tried the writing of json, but it should work too, and I know where to finetune my code if it does not.